# How to lock and protect columns but allow rows to be edited

Tags: excel, row, protected, editing, vba

I've Put in a code into a sheet so when the user double clicks on the cell, a new row is added below and the formulas are dragged down.

I'm wanting to disable the option to delete or insert any columns but allow rows to be inserted or deleted.

I've tried to lock and protect columns being edited, however it's stopping the rows from being edited.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`Protection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/protection-object-excel) property of the `Worksheet`. It has the following settings (amongst others):

- AllowDeletingColumns
- AllowDeletingRows
- AllowInsertingColumns
- AllowInsertingRows

So you can protect the sheet to allow insert and delete of row *but not* columns with:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ws.Unprotect
    ws.Cells.Locked = False
    ws.Protect AllowInsertingColumns:=False, _
        AllowDeletingColumns:=False, _
        AllowInsertingRows:=True, _
        AllowDeletingRows:=True

End Sub
```